# Post Title not showing (Astra Theme + Elementor)

Tags: elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

Any idea why Elementor does not display the post title?

- in Elementor the "Hide Title" option is disabled
- in Astra Post Editor the Toggle "Hide Title" is disabled
- under "Single Post Settings" the option "title und blog meta" are
  visible

any idea?

here is the link to the page:
https://commitly.com/blog/cash-flow/

Comment: Seems to be a problem or miss documentation from ASTRA team .. I hope they work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Elementor rips off the page title when in Astra settings for the page layout you select "Layout 2". Page titles are still being showed when you select "Layout 1".

I wanted to use "Layout 2", but I wanted the titles to be shown. So I selected "Layout 1" and reproduced "Layout 2" by CSS.

```
body:not(.home) .entry-header {
    background: #eeeeee;
    margin-left: -33.33%;
    margin-right: -33.33%;
    padding: 3em;
}

.page {
    padding-top: 0!important;
}
```